# RoboBrowser getting type error 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a kahoot spammer which inputs a pin number and a username, decided by the user. I'm getting a type error when I run this code:

```
import re
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

#Getting pin number for kahoot
pin = int(input("What is the pin number of the Kahoot?"))
# Getting number of bots to be deployed
number_of_bots = int(input("How many bots would you like?"))
#Getting base name
name = str(input("What would you like your bots' name to be (number will be added to the end of the name)?"))
#counter
counter = 0
#Number on end of name
num = 1

def joinKahoot(pin, number_of_bots, name):
    browser = RoboBrowser(history = True)
    #Connect to kahoot's website
    browser.open("https://kahoot.it/")
    pin_form = browser.get_form()
    pin_form['inputSession'].value == pin
    browser.submit_form(pin_form)

    name_form = browser.get_form()
    name_form["username"].value == name
    browser.submit_form(name_form)

#While counter is less than number_of_bots flood kahoot
while counter < number_of_bots:
    joinKahoot(pin, number_of_bots, name)
    counter += 1
    num += 1
    name = name + str(num)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vincent\Documents\Kahoot Spammer V2\flood.py", line 29, in <module>
    joinKahoot(pin, number_of_bots, name)
  File "C:\Users\Vincent\Documents\Kahoot Spammer V2\flood.py", line 20, in joinKahoot
    pin_form['inputSession'].value == pin
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is the     name_form["username"].value == name   comparisons the correct syntax or do you mean =

Comment: @rosh either way, I still get the same error.

Comment: It means that `browser.get_form()` returned `None`, then you tried to look up `None["username"]` which failed.

Comment: This both pin_form and name_form are NoneType objects.

Comment: @HughBothwell I don't mean to put you on the spot, as I assume you don't know much about robobrowser, but how would I go about fixing it so get_form() returns something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you are opening, `https://kahoot.it/#/`, does not contain an HTML `<form>` tag. The form you see is created using Javascript, undoubtedly to defeat DoS attacks using elementary HTML parsing techniques.

That is why `browser.get_form()` returns nothing. The function tries to return an instance of of `robobrowser.forms.form.Form`, which is a representation of an HTML form, but it can't find one.

I suspect you won't be able to get `robobrowser` to do what you want on this particular website. Good thing too.

Comment: How would I fill out that form?

Comment: I understand that the `selenium` module will execute the Javascript and present you with HTML you can parse.