# RoboBrowser get_form returns None where select returns the form

Tags: python, web-scraping, robobrowser

I'm trying to login on twino.eu with RoboBrowser. I can find the form using the `select` method but not via the `get_form` method. I saw other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44350046/robobrowser-getting-type-error-nonetype-object-is-not-subscriptable) regarding other pages where it says it doesn't work because the form would be loaded via JavaScript, but wouldn't then both methods fail?

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
url = 'https://www.twino.eu/en/login/'

browser = RoboBrowser(parser="html.parser")
browser.open(url)

login_form = browser.select("form[data-v-c808aa0a]") # works
login_form = browser.select("form.dark-text.mt-6") # works too
print(login_form)
login_form = browser.get_form(".dark-text") # does not work
print(login_form)
```

Output:

```
[<form class="dark-text mt-6" data-v-c808aa0a="" novalidate="novalidate"><div class="input-form y-centered-col my-4" data-v-01ffee96="" data-v-69d22072="" data-v-c808aa0a=""><div class="mb-1" data-v-69d22072=""><label data-v-69d22072="">Email</label></div> <input data-v-69d22072="" placeholder="E-mail" type="email" value=""/> <div class="invalid-input" data-v-69d22072="" style="display:none;"></div></div> <div class="input-form y-centered-col my-4" data-v-69d22072="" data-v-a62aff24="" data-v-c808aa0a=""><div class="mb-1" data-v-69d22072=""><label data-v-69d22072="">Password</label></div> <input data-v-69d22072="" placeholder="Password" type="password" value=""/> <div class="invalid-input" data-v-69d22072="" style="display:none;"></div></div> <!-- --> <a class="link small-text clickable mt-4" data-v-c808aa0a="" href="/en/password-recovery">
  Forgot your password?
</a> <button class="twino-button is-full mt-5 mb-3 main-button-effects" data-v-c808aa0a="" type="submit">
              Login
            </button> <div class="invalid-input" data-v-c808aa0a="" style="display:none;"></div> <div class="xy-centered mt-3" data-v-c808aa0a=""><label class="mr-1 small-text" data-v-c808aa0a="">Don't have an account?</label> <a class="link small-text level-item" data-v-c808aa0a="" href="https://www.twino.eu/en/registration/register" target="_blank">
  Register now
</a></div></form>]
None
```

Comment: The api says: `Find form by ID, as well as standard BeautifulSoup arguments.`. So either `id` or a bs4-style argument is needed. I don't think bs4 supports the dot-class notation. It would be `class_='className'`.

Comment: Thank you, I interpreted the dot-class notation as part of the standard arguments as it worked in `.select`. It does work now with e.g. `class_=dark-text`

Comment: Do you want to post it as an answer, @white?